# Visualize a graph with desired edges crossing

Tags: graph, visualization

Given a graph with vertices and edges, are any libraries or applications available in Java/C++ to visualize a graph that

Available attributes

- The graph is undirected and each vertex may have a weighted value.
- Each vertex could have a radius; any vertex within the radius has a chance to connect each other (just like a wireless network).

Target

- Maximize the crossing of edges
- Minimize the crossing of edges (Make it as planar as possible)

Is any layout or visualization algorithm to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of sounds like you are asking for both a graph generation script and a layout algorithm?   I think that Ron Davidson and David Harel's paper "Drawing graphs nicely using simulated annealing" ACM Transactions on Graphics Volume 15 Issue 4, Oct. 1996 Pages 301 - 331  included edge crossings as an explicit tuneable criteria. I don't remember if it include a vertex size dimension, and I'm not aware of C or Java implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jGraph it a graph visualization in java : http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html